# scrollintoview does not work until images have loaded

Tags: reactjs

In react the scroll into view (both method elem.scrollintoview() or react-scroll-to-component library doesnt work when I do the following:

Call scroll to view before the main images have finished loading.

Once the images have loaded (ie on the entire page) then the problem resolves both component and function now work.

I discovered this running a create-react-app locally and slowing the connection via dev tools to low speed 3g.

Anyone know any solutions?

Comment: Could you include the code in the question?